# Getting the id of selected item returns 0

Tags: java

I have two `JComboBoxes` where the other one dynamically changing the value based on user choices. I properly get the **id** of those selected item. But getting the first element of my `JComboBox` gives me a zero value where I wanted to get the id without firing the `ItemListener`.

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("Add".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            System.out.println("Position id is " + getPositionId());      
        }
    }
}

ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == department) {
            Department item = (Department) department.getSelectedItem();
            int departmentId = item.getId();
            model.setDeptId(departmentId);
            List<Position> list = model.getAllPositionId();
            DefaultComboBoxModel positionModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(list.toArray());
            position.setModel(positionModel);
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == position) {
            Position item = (Position) cbPosition.getSelectedItem();
            int positionId = item.getId();
            model.setPositionId(positionId);
        }
    }
}
```

Every time the user changed the selected value. `DefaultComboBoxModel` changed also its value with corresponding id. But getting it returns me `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution. I just created a void method outside the `ItemListener` where it gets the first element.